# returning Distinct Core Data Model in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Core Data to make an app for my bus stops. I want to only return one copy of a stop with the same name.  For example if I have bus stops of: [Mary, Jose, Harry, Jose]  Then I only want:[Mary, Jose, Harry] returned.  The duplicates are in my database because each bus stop has a different route.  However, I want to list all the different bus stops without duplicating them.  This is what I have tried bus I am still returning all my bus stops.  Thank you for your time.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class Stop: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var stop_name: String
    @NSManaged var stop_number: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var time: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var busParent: BusRoute
class func getDifferantStops() -> [Stop]?
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Stop")
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["stop_name"]

    if let fetchResults = CoreDataModel.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Stop] {
        return fetchResults

    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `propertiesToFetch` is ignored unless you also set

```
fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```